# Why most of the servers use redhat and not free ubuntu server?(problem transter to other software or redhat much better)

Tags: ubuntu, redhat, ubuntu-enterprise-cloud

Why most of the servers use redhat and not free ubuntu server LTS?

(problem transter to other software or redhat much better)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit hard to understand what you're asking here, but I'm going to take a guess:

"Why are people using Red Hat Enterprise (and similar commercial distributions) instead of Ubuntu, wich is free?"

The simple answer (to a very broad question): Vendor support.

Comment: Just noting that Ubuntu recently added professional support See -  (http://www.canonical.com/enterprise-services/ubuntu-advantage/support) Ubuntu even provides support for "cloud" specifically if you care about that. I guess redhat started first, has done a good job and thus has a big following, but I know thousands are using or starting to use Ubuntu server now, and it's serving them just fine as well

Answer (score 1):

More to the point:  (1) companies generally want to buy support contracts, which they can get from Red Hat or SuSE but not from Canonical; (2) commercial software for Linux almost always supports supports Red Hat, often supports Novell/SuSE, and rarely Ubuntu.

Comment: I need for web server that holds websites, in this case I think commercial software not needed

Comment: @user43353 - then there's no need to ask this question: install the OS you want, and run with it :)